# ASP.NET MVC4 Debugging on IIS Local Server with a different port

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, port

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC4 application in Visual Studio 2010. Up to now I have been debugging on the IIS server on my machine using port 80. However, my application needs to communicate with remote clients, and in order to do this we have changed the port that points to my machine to 1080. The problem now is that when I try and debug the application in Visual Studio it won't deploy! When closing and reopening Visual Studio it refuses to load this project until I manually alter the settings in the .csproj file. Is there any way I can tell Visual Studio that a different port is being used, or do I have to use port 80 when debugging? Thanks.

[image: Error message]

[image: These are the bindings in my IIS for the site I am using:]

[image: And these are the deployment settings in Visual Studio:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, IIS now listens on port 1080. You'll also have to configure that for your "Project Url":

```
http://localhost:1080/ConnectManager2
```